# Не могу авторизовать юзера.

Tags: pdo, php, cookie

Не могу понять, что я делаю не так. Ткните носом в проблему. Потому что авторизация проходит, куки создаются. Но понять что я авторизован я не могу. Толи запрос в бд не идет, толи есть другая причина.

```
<?php

class User {

    public $logged = false;

    public function __construct(){
        global $db;

        if(isset($_COOKIE['logged'])){
            $auth = explode(':', base64_decode($_COOKIE['logged']));

            $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id and password = :password LIMIT 1"); 
            $sql->execute(array(':id' => $auth[0], ':password' => $auth[1]));
            $check = $sql->fetchColumn();
            $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            var_dump($check);
            var_dump($user);

            if ($check == true) {
            $this->logged = true;
            $this->id = $user['id'];
            $this->firstname = $user['firstname'];
            $this->secondname = $user['secondname'];
            }
        }
    }

    # получаем ид
    public function getID(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    # получаем имя и фамилию
    public function getFirstName(){
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function getSecondName(){
        return $this->secondname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хранить логин пароль в куках не бесопасно, лучше при логине генерируй хеш и записывай его в куки и базу, а потом сравнивай хеш.

self::$logged = true; попробуй

Comment: Для начала, мне бы с этим разобраться. а потом уже генерить хэши

Comment: Ну так а `var_dump($check);` что выводит? Не удивлюсь, если `string(0)`...

Comment: boolen false либо null

Comment: пароль в кавычки возми (возможно запрос не выполняется).

Comment: Исправьте на `$check = $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Comment: "Исправьте на $check = $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);" в итоге мы ничего не получим кроме синт.ошибки

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте для начала выставить в PDO уровень обработки ошибок, чтобы увидеть, что запросы хотя бы выполняются

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: ничего не вывело, потому что запросы выполняются, ибо регистрация проходит, и при авторизации время последней авторизации обновляется. плюс к этому обработка ошибок была изначально установлена

Comment: var_dump($_COOKIE) делали?

Comment: естественно делал. и вот результат

array (size=2)
  'PHPSESSID' => string 'e4be6l3vsus8f6ol3bn3mr3io6' (length=26)
  'logged' => string 'Ojg5N2M4ZmRlMjVjNWNjNTI3MGNkYTYxNDI1ZWVkM2M4' (length=44)

как видно куки впорядке

Comment: у вас куки не содержат id (`$auth[0]==""`). а вы пытаетесь по id найти пользователя. 

    Ojg5N2M4ZmRlMjVjNWNjNTI3MGNkYTYxNDI1ZWVkM2M4 => :897c8fde25c5cc5270cda61425eed3c8

ЗЫ http://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: спасибо. исправил.

теперь не получается вывести инфу юзера в шаблон, то есть не получаю данные о юзере.

var_dump($user); = boolean false

Comment: не пойму можно так или нет, потому что работает что-то одно

------
   $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email and password = :password LIMIT 1"); 
   $sql->execute(array(':email' => $auth[0], ':password' => $auth[1]));
   $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $check = $sql->fetchColumn();

Comment: всё понял fetchColumn() заменить на rowCount()

Собственно благодарю Yura Ivanov, ткнул носом туда куда нужно.